# What is the noun of "to credit something to somebody"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns, terminology, finance

I'm working with digital securities. You can think about company shares. If an investor buys those shares, it is a process with several steps. At the end, the issuer gives the shares to the investor:

> The issuer **credits** the shares to the investor.

What is that process as a noun? Is that "a credit"? A "creditation"? Something else?

Comment: An accreditation is definitely not the same as a credit.

Comment: Using the verbal noun *crediting* is a possibility. There may be a technical finance term, though.

Comment: Considering that the entity who gives the shares is the "issuer", I'd suggest "issuance". Wikipedia does mention this particular term when talking about [bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_(finance)#Issuance)

Answer (score 1):

> The issuer ***places***  the shares with the investor.

> A share placing (or placement) is when new equity shares are issued to individual investors, corporate entities, or small groups of investors for capital. This increases the amount of shares in issue and dilutes existing shareholders. Share placings usually go to institutions to fund company growth.

([www.shiftingshares.com](http://www.shiftingshares.com))

Answer (score 0):

You have options:

- *issuance*
- *allotment*
- *allocation*

> Issuing shares is a term used when shares are being issued to a to-be
> shareholder in the company. The reason this person is the to-be
> shareholder is because they would eventually own the shares of the
> company after issuance. The process of issuing shares to a person is
> called issuance, allotment or allocation.
>  <sub>Source:
> [Equvista—Issuing
> Shares](https://eqvista.com/terminology/issuing-shares/)</sub>